# How to enforce declaring using for specific interface in dll

Tags: c#, dll

I need some methods from my dll to be accessible only if user specifically declares using with interface containing those methods.

In dll named MathProcessor, there are two Interfaces

```
public interface IBasicFunctions
{
    int Add(int x, int y)
}
```

and

```
public interface IAdvancedFunctions
{
    double Divide(int x, int y)
}
```

I need to prepare the dll so the when the user wants to use advanced functions, he would have to declare also

```
using MathProcessor.IAdvancedFunctions
```

Otherwise he has access only to IBasicFunctions when declaring using only for MathProcessor.

Comment: create the namespace in order to use it? Place the base-interface in namespace `MathProcessor`, and the `IAdvancedFunctions`-interface into the `MathProcessor.IAdvancedFunctions`-namespace

Comment: Your request makes little sense. You generally import namespaces, not types. You can import types but it's rare to do so. No one needs to import anything anyway. It's just a shortcut to not have to qualify type names. Also, your interface would need to be implemented in a class and it's only the namespace of that class that the consuming code has to know about. Someone could implement both interfaces in the same class. Only if the implementation is explicit would the interface namespace be required.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It seems that I am looking for Extension methods. By setting namespace this functionality can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

This is solvable by extension methods. In that case the implementation requires explicit declaration of using for namespace containing extension methods.